# Me Podrian Ayudar, tengo un problema con AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Acabo de implementar un buscador en tiempo real con ayuda de AJAX en Laravel.
me gustaría saber como hago para que cuando mi input este vacio no me muestre datos. y que cuando vuelva a escribir me traiga los datos.

y también quisiera saber si es que se puede poner un limite de cuantos datos se puede traer como máximo. Para no sobrecargar la página.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
            $value=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                data:{'search':$value},
                success:function(data){
                $('#datos').html(data);
                }
            });
            })

</script>
```

```html
<div class="md-form mt-0">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id = "search" name = "search" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample1"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">
</div>
```

---

Nose si me explique bien, Esto pasa cuando no escribo nada [image]

Y cuando escribo un nombre, gracias a ajax me trae todos los datos. Pero, al borrar los que escribí en el buscador todos los datos los deja abierto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de que cuando se borre todo del input... no me cargue los datos? o ajax ya funciona así.

Comment: Hola @CarlosS, puedes validar dentro de success que la data con un if , si está vacía le asignas un valor o algo que quieras en caso contrario que muestre lo que tu llamaste, eso se me ocurre. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar sobrecargar la api es recomendable que le hagas un throttle. Esto evitará que llames a la api con cada tecla que presionas y lo hagas a 0.2 segundos después de que termines de escribir

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let espera = null;

        $('#search').on('keyup',function(){

            if (espera != null) 
                clearTimeout(espera)

            espera = setTimeout(throttle, 200, this)
        })

        function throttle (esto) {

            $value=$(esto).val();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                data:{'search':$value},
                success:function(data){
                $('#datos').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Y con respecto a limitar el número de datos, desde el propio endpoint de la api puedes limitar el número de datos que sacas. Asumiré que estarás usando eloquent para sacar los datos así que has de añadir el siguiente método:

```
take(número de datos)
```

Comment: el take() donde se pone, esa parte no entendí. Eso es parte del JavaScript verdad?

Comment: El Take va en la parte de Laravel, donde llamas para recibir los resultados. Y si necesitas que no aparezca nada si el campo esta vacio, añade esto en el evento " if ($(this).val() === '') { $('#datos').html(''); return;} "

Comment: dependiendo de los datos chequear el length también puede ayudar algo onda `.val().length > 3 `

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es usar un condicional if antes de enviar el ajax, de esta manera corroboras si se envia algo o no.

En este caso te recomdaria usar la propiedad length, puedes verla aqui.[Propiedad Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/length)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
        $value=$(this).val();
        if(value.length() == 0){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                data:{'search':$value},
                success:function(data){
                $('#datos').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```